# Why do I get an SQL parsing error when I use parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I'm working on a database application in Webmatrix.  I have a cshtml file which is supposed to update a record in the database. Everything works correctly if I use string concatenation for the SQL command, but I know that's not safe.  So, I'm attempting to use parameters instead.  But I get an SQL parsing error when I do.

Works:

```
@{
    string dbName = Request["db"];
    string tble = Request["t"];
    string idName = Request["idn"];
    string id = Request["id"];
    string field = Request["f"];
    string value = Request["v"];

    var db = Database.Open(dbName);
    var result = db.Execute("UPDATE ["+tble+"] SET ["+field+"]='"+value+"' WHERE ["+idName+"]='"+id+"'");
    <text>Result: @result</text>
}
```

Causes Error:

```
@{
    string dbName = Request["db"];
    string tble = Request["t"];
    string idName = Request["idn"];
    string id = Request["id"];
    string field = Request["f"];
    string value = Request["v"];

    var db = Database.Open(dbName);
    var result = db.Execute("UPDATE @0 SET @1=@2 WHERE @3=@4",tble,field,value,idName,id);
    @*var result = db.Execute("UPDATE ["+tble+"] SET ["+field+"]='"+value+"' WHERE ["+idName+"]='"+id+"'");*@
    <text>Result: @result</text>
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvdlx.png)

Comment: table and column names cannot be passed as parameters

Comment: Please don't do this! A query is where you commit yourself. Your query is the exact programming equivalent of booking a wedding before choosing the bride (or groom, must get into the habit).

Comment: Wanting to parameterize table and column names is usually a sign of a broken data model. Data of the same "type", that ought to be stored in *one* column in *one* table has instead been dispersed among multiple tables and columns. Oftentimes, you'll then discover that you want to write queries against this data that aren't straightforward because the data is dispersed (having to name many tables and columns in the query and repeat conditions) and that some *data* has been embedded into these table and column *names* when it should have been modelled *as data*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterized SQL commands do not accept table or column names since it would allow for potential SQL injection attacks. It is a security feature.

It is generally a bad design choice to allow table and column names from a form or request to be passed into an SQL string.

A better approach is to use integer values and map those to their corresponding tables or columns.

That way you avoid, or at least make it more difficult for, someone with malicious intent to access sensitive data that was never meant to be exposed through the request or form in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = db.Execute("UPDATE ["+tble+"] SET ["+field+"]=@1 WHERE ["+idName+"]=@2",value,id);
```